# Unable to install cdk-minishift on RHEL8 (No-Cost RHEL Developer Subscription)

Tags: openshift

Ref: https://developers.redhat.com/products/cdk/hello-world/#fndtn-rhel 
Have a RHEL8 with the nocost sub and trying to install cdk-minishift but get unable to find match.

yum install cdk-minishift Updating Subscription Management repositories. 
Last metadata expiration check: 0:42:48 ago on Fri 31 May 2019 21:21:08 BST. No match for argument: cdk-minishift Error: Unable to find a match

cat /etc/redhat-release Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.0 (Ootpa)

subscription-manager status +-------------------------------------------+ System Status Details +-------------------------------------------+ Overall Status: Current System Purpose Status: Not Specified
subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-server-devtools-rpms Error: 'rhel-7-server-devtools-rpms' does not match a valid repository ID. Use "subscription-manager repos --list" to see valid repositories.

The guide say to use rhel-7-server-devtools-rpms and rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms but this a redhat 8 build?

Does the guide need updating for rhel8?
Have nothing that comes close to devtools?

subscription-manager repos --list | grep tools Repo ID: satellite-tools-6.5-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms Repo URL: https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/layered/rhel8/x86_64/sat-tools/6.5/os Repo ID: satellite-tools-6.5-for-rhel-8-x86_64-debug-rpms Repo URL: https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/layered/rhel8/x86_64/sat-tools/6.5/debug Repo ID: satellite-tools-6.5-for-rhel-8-x86_64-source-rpms Repo URL: https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/layered/rhel8/x86_64/sat-tools/6.5/source/SRPMS
What am I doing wrong?